# ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64')

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn, pandas, numpy

I am trying to fit my data into my model which takes numpy as input, so I feed the model with the dataframe values

```
stacked_averaged_models.fit(train.values, y_train1)
```

I am getting the following error

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-145-9ba69af8df05> in <module>()
      1 X_traintrain = train.as_matrix().astype(np.float)
      2 from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
----> 3 stacked_averaged_models.fit(train.values, y_train1)
      4 stacked_train_pred = stacked_averaged_models.predict(train.values)
      5 stacked_pred = np.expm1(stacked_averaged_models.predict(test.values))

<ipython-input-140-dfca4af6e9d1> in fit(self, X, y)
     18                 instance = clone(model)
     19                 self.base_models_[i].append(instance)
---> 20                 instance.fit(X[train_index], y[train_index])
     21                 y_pred = instance.predict(X[holdout_index])
     22                 out_of_fold_predictions[holdout_index, i] = y_pred

~\Anaconda3\envs\deeplearning\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py in fit(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    248         Xt, fit_params = self._fit(X, y, **fit_params)
    249         if self._final_estimator is not None:
--> 250             self._final_estimator.fit(Xt, y, **fit_params)
    251         return self
    252 

~\Anaconda3\envs\deeplearning\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\coordinate_descent.py in fit(self, X, y, check_input)
    705                              order='F', dtype=[np.float64, np.float32],
    706                              copy=self.copy_X and self.fit_intercept,
--> 707                              multi_output=True, y_numeric=True)
    708             y = check_array(y, order='F', copy=False, dtype=X.dtype.type,
    709                             ensure_2d=False)

~\Anaconda3\envs\deeplearning\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_X_y(X, y, accept_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, multi_output, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, y_numeric, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    574     if multi_output:
    575         y = check_array(y, 'csr', force_all_finite=True, ensure_2d=False,
--> 576                         dtype=None)
    577     else:
    578         y = column_or_1d(y, warn=True)

~\Anaconda3\envs\deeplearning\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    451                              % (array.ndim, estimator_name))
    452         if force_all_finite:
--> 453             _assert_all_finite(array)
    454 
    455     shape_repr = _shape_repr(array.shape)

~\Anaconda3\envs\deeplearning\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in _assert_all_finite(X)
     42             and not np.isfinite(X).all()):
     43         raise ValueError("Input contains NaN, infinity"
---> 44                          " or a value too large for %r." % X.dtype)
     45 
     46 

ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').
```

I did a check on NaN and infinity, it did pass the test

```
X_traintrain = train.as_matrix().astype(np.float)
print(np.any(np.isnan(X_traintrain)))
print(np.all(np.isfinite(X_traintrain)))
```

Output:

```
False
True
```

How else can I solve, or at least, debug this?

```
X1      X2       X3     X4       X5    X6   X7     X8   Y1      Y2
0.64    784.00  343.00  220.50  3.50    5   0.00    0   10.56   16.67
0.62    808.50  367.50  220.50  3.50    2   0.00    0   8.60    12.07
0.62    808.50  367.50  220.50  3.50    5   0.00    0   8.50    12.04
0.98    514.50  294.00  110.25  7.00    2   0.10    1   24.58   26.47
```

This is few rows of my dataset

Comment: You most probably have inf or nan still. Use imputer for instance to solve it. See here https://s3.amazonaws.com/assets.datacamp.com/production/course_3374/slides/ch3_slides.pdf   plz let me know if it helped then I can turn it into an answer later.

Comment: Yes, i double checked for missing values both in dataframe and array format.

Comment: @KasraManshaei I will give it a try and comment here, thanks :)

Comment: Does your data contain strings somewhere? If you can, please post the code and a sample of data and also your dataframe size.

Comment: I am sorry for late reply, its a complete numerical dataset. I will post some features and sameple data on the question

Comment: @SriHari actually I guess it's so weird, can you add the code before your fit function?

Answer (score 1):

I have tried so many suggested solutions but I found this one solve the problem.

`data =data[~data.isin([np.nan, np.inf, -np.inf]).any(1)]`

Answer (score 0):

See if one of the answers in [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31323499/sklearn-error-valueerror-input-contains-nan-infinity-or-a-value-too-large-for) is helpful.
In my case, the error was caused by a `df = df.reindex(index=my_index)`: The dataframe's index started at 1, but `my_index` contained a 0, so pandas silently inserted a row full of NaNs...